# How can I install Perl version under my home using perlbrew?

Tags: perl, installation, perlbrew

I have installed [perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/~gugod/App-perlbrew-0.10/) which seems like a good solution, but I get some meaningless  error when actually trying to install some Perl version:

```
$ perlbrew install perl-5.12.1
Attempting to load conf from /home/dave/perl5/perlbrew/Conf.pm
Fail to get http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.12.1 (error: ) at /home/dave/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew line 1277.
```

Comment: You get that error when it fails to find/download the Perl source code.  So could be internet or firewall issues?

Comment: ubuntu 10.04. I have proxy enabled. wget works, also git and cpan (this is how I first installed it).

Comment: BTW, perl 5.12.2 was released recently: http://news.perlfoundation.org/2010/09/perl-5122-released.html

Comment: @draegtun by the way, is there a way to ask perlbrew for a list of perl versions available for install?

Comment: I don't think `perlbrew` has this option because it just slavishly pulls down the perl you request, for eg `perlbrew install perl-5.12.3` (it would try and give an error until one day 5.12.3 is actually there!).  So yes this would be a very nice feature for `perlbrew` to have.  In the meantime I just quickly put together this script to get a list of available perl versions: http://gist.github.com/584025

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your comments do you have `http_proxy` ENV variable set in your shell?

```
$ env | grep http_proxy
```

If not then set it with your proxy settings and re-try perlbrew install:

```
 $ export http_proxy = "http://yourProxyURLorIP:8080"
 $ perlbrew install perl-5.12.1
```

`perlbrew` uses this ENV variable to pick up the proxy server.  If this ENV variable isn't set then it tries the normal direct HTTP connection (see [line 1274 in perlbrew current master on Github](http://github.com/gugod/App-perlbrew/blob/master/perlbrew#L1274))

```
$ua->proxy($ENV{http_proxy}) if $ENV{http_proxy};
```

If that doesn't work then have a look at [`HTTP::Lite`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Lite/).  This is what [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-perlbrew/) uses under the hood to fetch source code.  *NB. perlbrew uses its own copy of HTTP::Lite*

Finally if still no luck you mentioned that you "first installed it" via CPAN.  The docs does mention issues when upgrading from a previous CPAN version.  This maybe something further you need to look into?

**Update**  Test this [`HTTP::Lite`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Lite/) script and let me know what you see (NB. You may need to install [`HTTP::Lite`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Lite/)):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTTP::Lite;

my $ua = HTTP::Lite->new;

$ua->proxy("yourProxyURLorIP:8080");  # <= http_proxy env minus "http://"

my $req = $ua->request( 'http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.12.1/' ) 
    or die "Unable to get document: $!";


print $ua->body();   # <= if you get this then all is good!
```

I think you've probably been hit by a known bug with [`HTTP::Lite`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Lite/), see RT issue [uri style proxy env vars fail to set the proxy and port correctly](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=61108).

The above code is the workaround to this bug.  I assume the same bug is in `perlbrew` copy of [`HTTP::Lite`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Lite/).  If it is then removing the `http://` from your http_proxy ENV would resolve the problem (famous last words!)

**Update 2**

Just to make my last comment clear when you run `perlbrew` you can do this (from shell like `bash`):

```
http_proxy=IPaddr:Port perlbrew install perl-5.12.1
```

You would need to always prefix every `perlbrew` command like this, at least until `HTTP::Lite` or `perlbrew` proxy bug is fixed.

Alternative to above is you can just patch your local version just be adding the following before line 1277:

```
$ENV{http_proxy} = "IPaddr:Port";   # <= your proxy IP & port
```

Hopefully we've finally cracked it!  Let me know if all successful because if so then I'll post a fix to [Gugod](http://github.com/gugod) (author of `perlbrew`) with necessary local changes to `HTTP::Lite`.

Comment: What version of perlbrew are you using? That line I mentioned above hasn't always been there :(  You can check by doing `grep http_proxy ~/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew`.  The latest version of perlbrew is 0.10

Comment: Just checked commit history on Github and the ENV http_proxy line was only added at version 0.9 on 3rd August.  So upgrading to latest version should fix your problems (touch wood!)

Comment: I think I'm using the latest, just downloaded  it a couple of says ago. `grep http_proxy ~/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew` gives `$ua->proxy($ENV{http_proxy}) if $ENV{http_proxy};`

Comment: Fingers crossed its the `http://` bug in the proxy code of `HTTP::Lite`!  See my update.

Comment: +1 draegtun, I followed your instructions and it seems to work. So should I change my env proxy somehow? When I use my Ubuntu Preferences->Network Proxy the proxy is written without any `http://` (but when I `echo $http_proxy` it's with `http://`. So, what should I do -- and will this (what I should do...) might affect other stuff?

Comment: @David B: Yes I'm not sure of the side effects of changing http_proxy env on other things.  However you can safely do the following each time with no side effects: `http_proxy=IPaddress:Port perlbrew ...`.  This only sets the env variable for the command that follows it.  So can use this until `HTTP::Lite / perlbrew` is fixed?  Or alternatively add `$ENV{http_proxy}="IPaddr:Port"` to you `perlbrew` script locally.